# The worst case or the worst case scenario

Tags: grammaticality

If I say

> “He is kidnapped, or the worst case may be murdered.”

Does this sentence make sense?
Or should I say

> ”He is kidnapped, or the worst case scenario may be murdered.”

Or even

> “He is kidnapped, or the worst possibility may be murdered.”

Answer (score 1):

"Murdered" is not regarded as a state of being. You probably would not hear a conversation like this: "How is Frank?"  "Not too well, really. He is murdered."

It is hardly necessary to say that getting murdered is the worst case. Just say,

> He was kidnapped, and may have been murdered.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct. However, there should be, I believe, the **IN** preposition added in both cases.

*He is kidnapped, or **IN** the worst case scenario may be murdered.*

*He is kidnapped, or **IN** the worst case may be murdered.*

Moreover, there are some grammatical errors within your question per se.